# Private link to view closed entry

Tags: channel-entries, links, secure

I need to be able to generate private links for entries that aren't visible on the front-end of the website. I guess I could just setup an alternative template that isn't linked within the website structure. The links don't need to be very secure but this still feels a bit half-baked. Has anyone setup something like this before?

Comment: If they aren't visible on the front-end of the website then there's not much point linking to them(?). The standard approach for this would be to limit access to a particular Member Group and then when the user is logged in on the front-end and authenticated as part of that member group then they'd be able to see the content whereas all other users wouldn't. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: An example use-case is sending an external contributor a link to the entry for approval before it's published or giving special customers advanced previews before an item is publicly available. I want to avoid user having to login.

Comment: Better Workflow has a feature called "external previews" designed specifically for the purpose you just described, Dylan. http://betterworkflow.electricputty.co.uk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be particularly secure, create a separate sub-domain, and set up a global variable to show different statuses depending on which sub-domain they're on. If you're using [FocusLab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) this is simple, otherwise try something like this in your main public index.php file under where it says "CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES":

```
switch($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]) { 
  case "previews.domain.com" : 
    $assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://previews.domain.com/'; 
    $assign_to_config['global_vars']['gv_entry_statuses'] = 'open|Draft';
    break;  
  case "www.domain.com" :
  case "domain.com" :
    $assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://www.domain.com/';
    $assign_to_config['global_vars']['gv_entry_statuses'] = 'open';
    break;
}
```

Then any time you use a channel entries tag, add the parameter `status="{gv_entry_statuses}"`

You can use this technique to allow editors a quick and simple workflow for creating new content before launching to the live site. Rather than using the 'closed' status you should really create a new custom status for this, such as "draft" or "pending", because it's useful to keep "closed" for stuff that really should never appear anywhere *ever* (but for some reason needs to be kept in the system).

You can also use this technique for quick and dirty forking into separate templates, e.g. you could specify a different folder for tmpl_file_basepath using `$assign_to_config['tmpl_file_basepath']` so that the sub-domain displays a completely different version of the site. (Much better to use a proper version-controlled environment with Git deployments, but that can take a while to set up and is not necessary for really small sites.)

Comment: Very clever technique! I like it.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a nice approach and I'm already setup with the FocusLab Master config and git so it should be pretty simple to implement.